# Root system of Lie algebra: right angle => not simple?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Why is it that if the roots of a Lie algebra form angles of 90 degrees, the Lie algebra is not simple? Is it because the said roots commute with each other and so the Lie algebra can be broken down to nontrivial two-sided ideals? If that is the case, then why are these roots not a part of the Cartan subalgebra (maximal subspace of commuting Hermitian generators)?

Comment: Just to clarify: Many simple root systems do contain *some* roots which are perpendicular to each other (e.g. look at $B_2$; actually, I think all except $A_1$ and $A_2$ contain such orthogonal pairs of roots). What you must mean is that if the root system consists of two sets $R_1,R_2$ such that *all* roots in $R_1$ are perpendicular to *all* in $R_2$, then the root system and hence the Lie algebra is not simple. This is indeed shown in the question linked to by Moishe Kohan.

Comment: Also, roots are never part of a Cartan subalgebra -- what is your definition of the roots of a Lie algebra?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I guess I was just a bit confused how roots can be orthogonal to each other, but I think I've figured out why -- is it because these roots do not commute with *all* of the generators in the Cartan algebra?

Comment: In my terminology, roots cannot commute or not commute with something in the Cartan subalgebra -- they live in different spaces. Rather, two roots being orthogonal to each other corresponds to *their respective root spaces in the Lie algebra commuting with each other*. This happens quite regularly as soon as matrices are big enough. E.g. $\pmatrix{0&*&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&*\\0&0&0&0}$ commute with each other, corresponding to simple roots $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_3$ in the root system $A_3$ being orthogonal to each other.